# Options for Repairing Hole in Wall

Tags: hole, hole-repair

This is my first time dealing with the problem of a hole in the wall. As of a few minutes ago, I accidentally knocked over my very heavy room divider and the corner of it went straight through the opposite wall. The hole isn't very big, but it isn't small either; I measured with my phone and it says the hole is roughly 6 and a half inches wide.

I wasn't sure how to handle fixing it because I've never had to deal with something like this before (I also rent). I'm currently between Task Rabbit-ing someone to fix it or actually hiring a business (from Google). Which would be cheaper/more efficient? I'm leaning towards business/company but not sure which would be more cost efficient for a hole that doesn't seem like that big of a deal but definitely not something I trust myself to tackle.

Comment: Without a picture of the hole, you will get nothing but guesses from us here.  Add a pic and tell us more about your skills and what tools you have. If you absolutely do not trust yourself to do the repair, this sounds like something a Handyman should be able to do.

Comment: Press the edit button and the press the icon that looks like two mountains and a sun, to add a photo.